# How iOS app switch hdmi input when starting airplay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, airplay

Are there any solutions in how iOS app switch hdmi input when starting airplay?

I want to switch HDMI-input when tap a airplay icon on my iphone app automatically,
just like google-chromecast.

I use MPMovieplayer to play my movies.
ofcourse, i can see a movie playing when switch HDMI manually.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Just not good to stick the question just in the title so thought I would move it into the actual question body itself. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you as airplay isn't my specialty but don't worry they're plenty of people on here who know it like the back of there hand. Good coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found i can't do that.

AppleTV does not support HDMI-CEC.

So we can't have any code switch hdmi-input by Starting AirPlay.

It was not caused by codes, caused by hardware.